# Is there a way to include multiple variables in a where clause in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make a where clause check 2 conditions but i don't know the syntax to do multiple ones.
I've already researched doing it with 1 int variable and it looked like this.

```
c.execute("SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Trials_Store WHERE Product_Code = ?",(LastP,))
```

Note that `LastP` is a int variable.
I want to include another int variable called `Last_ID` and The other condition is checking if `ID` is bigger than `Last_ID`.
Is there a way to include both of them in the condition? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prepared statement can have any number of placeholders, e.g.

```
sql = "SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Trials_Store WHERE Product_Code = ? AND ID > ?"
c.execute(sql, (LastP, Last_ID,))
```